# Barcode not reading

Tags: barcode-scanner

I generated some barcodes and scanned using kodak i1220 scanner, but the barcode values are not displaying. I've checked the barcode type on the scanner and its the same as that generated. Please,what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried a different barcode printed on something else, for example a drink bottle?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say with so little information. My suggestion is to take a working barcode, use the code to generate a new barcode image using your program. Are they really identical?

If so, the contrast between the black and white parts could be too low.